# Open File Without Direct Input

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am creating a javascript+html file that access 15-20 text files in the same folder. I need to read the the files line-by-line. The user is supposed to select a few checkboxes and radio buttons which, through some functions will tell java which files to open. The user CANNOT directly open the files, so  doesn't work for this. This is not a server based file, everything is stored in one folder on the computer.

The files are not all read each use, only certain files based on checkboxes the user selected. The user does not need to see the file an any way, I just need to store the lines as variables.

I am very new to javascript, in fact this is my first real project so I don't really know where to start. Everything I have found involves either file input or opening a new window using the file path.